# Full Screen Background images for iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone

What size and that names I need to use in ios7? I s there any guid for this part of development?

Comment: Yes, indeed there are..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If developing on XCode>5.0 use `.xcassets` file. It is normally in your file directory under `images.xcassets`.